# pandas does not add suffix to conflicting columns when merging multiindex

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I'm trying to merge two dataframes with MultiIndexes. Both contain the same columns and an ID field. The merge operates on the ID, all other columns should get suffixes. But only some of them do.

For the example, I'm using an empty dataframe, the behaviour is the same after adding data:

```
index_tuples=[]

for word_group in ["a", "b", "c"]:
    for correctness in ["1", "2"]:
        index_tuples.append([word_group, correctness])

index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(index_tuples, names=["outer", "inner"])

frame_x = pd.DataFrame(columns = index)
frame_x["id"]=""

frame_y = pd.DataFrame(columns = index)
frame_y["id"]=""

print(frame_x.merge(frame_y, on="id").columns)
```

this prints:

```
MultiIndex([('a_x', '1'),
            ('a_x', '2'),
            (  'b', '1'),
            (  'b', '2'),
            ('c_x', '1'),
            ('c_x', '2'),
            ('a_y', '1'),
            ('a_y', '2'),
            (  'b', '1'),
            (  'b', '2'),
            ('c_y', '1'),
            ('c_y', '2'),
            ( 'id',  '')],
           names=['outer', 'inner'])
```

As you can see, one of the MultiIndex columns has not received the added suffix. This behaviour doesn't occur with just two outer columns in the MultiIndex, then both get the suffix. For four outer columns ("a", "b", "c", "d"), just two get suffixed.

What is pandas doing here ?

UPDATE:
Some comments pointed out that the problem can't be reproduced. I couldn't reproduce it either, so I deleted the question, then it reoccurred. This is python 3.6, pandas 0.25.1. The problem seems to be non-deterministic. It appears with different combinations on the MultiIndex, sometimes it doesn't happen at all. I took a video:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z5x2R.jpg

high-res version:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgINP.jpg

Comment: on pandas version 0.20.3 I get `levels=[['a_x', 'a_y', 'b_x', 'b_y', 'c_x', 'c_y', 'id'], ['', '1', '2']]`

Comment: with the current version 0.25.1 I also get `[('a_x', '1'),
            ('a_x', '2'),
            ('b_x', '1'),
            ('b_x', '2'),
            ('c_x', '1'),
            ('c_x', '2'),
            ('a_y', '1'),
            ('a_y', '2'),
            ('b_y', '1'),
            ('b_y', '2'),
            ('c_y', '1'),
            ('c_y', '2'),
            ( 'id',  '')]`

Comment: for me with `'0.25.0'` the `c` columns are duplicated...

Comment: It's very strange. In the same setup as yesterday evening, I now can't reproduce the issue, deleting the question

Comment: and undeleting the question. Currently recording a video of the strange behaviour. It's pandas 0.25.1